# Is it possible to organize Doctrine 1.2.x query result to have single array instead of multidimensional

Tags: join, doctrine

Currently with all my inner and left joins I get multidimensional array in result. Is there a way to get result as single array, so for instance instead of something like that

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        'name'   => 'Sample',
        [TABLE2] => Array(
            'name' => 'Connected sample'
        ),
    ),
)
```

get something like

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        'name'        => 'Sample',
        'table2.name' => 'Connected sample',
    ),
)
```

or if column has different name, then

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        'name' => 'Sample',
        'job'  => 'Connected sample',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why would you do something like that, but you can always map joined column to primary result:

```
$query->addSelect("(SELECT t.column FROM Table2 t WHERE t.table1_id=o.id) AS job") ;
```

Just an example, presuming your primary alias is "o" and it is one-2-one. No joins needed here.

Comment: Haven't you ever done inner join on some table? Well it is the same. Currently it makes an hierarchy with joined table inside. Will try your example thanks.